# Firestore rules : check the existence of a value in array

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to give permission of read and write just to users whom exist in the members group but I don't know why it doesn't work ?

This is the rules in firestore :

```
    rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /Users/{uid} {
  allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == uid;
  allow read : if request.auth != null;
  }
    
    match /GroupChat/{document=**} {
      allow read,create,update: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid in request.resource.data.Members;
        
    }
  }
}
```

This is a screen of my data base [image: screen from DATABase]

The query :

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("GroupChat")
          .where("Members",
              arrayContains: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
          .snapshots(),
```

when I want to display the information in my APP, I get this error :

> W/Firestore(14600): (24.0.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(GroupChat where Members array_contains 0FQhApDgWMVNTpOiDewF3qJX7IA3 order by **name**);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

Comment: Have you run the app in real device?

Comment: No,I didn't yet

Comment: error description=Disconnecting idle stream can be the cause of emulator please check in the real device then reply back.

Comment: I think I have a problem to run my Iphone with xcode so I just restart the IDLE and now it give me this error :
W/Firestore(14600): (24.0.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(GroupChat where Members array_contains 0FQhApDgWMVNTpOiDewF3qJX7IA3 order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
I changed it in the body of my question
Thank you @Debjeet

Comment: Can you share the query that you are making ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj , I added it in the question body

Comment: Can you try changing rule to `request.auth.uid in resource.data.Members;` instead of `request.auth.uid in request.resource.data.Members;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation),

> The `resource` variable refers to the requested document, and `resource.data` is a map of all of the fields and values stored in the document.

However, `request.resource.data` contains data that is being added in document in update/write operations. You should be using `resource.data` because you want to check existing data.

```
match /GroupChat/{document=**} {
  allow read,create,update: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid in resource.data.Members;        
}
```